# How to prevent or stop a denial of revenue attack?

Tags: security

In the case of paid for by advertising appliance ware websites, their fiscal survival depends heavily on revenue from advertising and managing costs.

If someone where to orchestrate a click-fraud campaign through a specific website/publisher, from the advertisers perspective the natural action would be to blame & ban the publisher's accounts and then forfeit unposted revenue.  Subsequently the publisher would have to scramble to a new advertising broke or agency, still leaving them vulnerable to the same thing happening again and again until they're out of advertisers or stop being profitable.

Tack on a random script to repeatedly, but in a throttled manner, fetch expensive resources over time to increase operating costs and eventually the publisher website will be dead.

From a developer standpoint, I can't see any way to avoid or stop such an attack.   Most advertising brokers would not release raw HTTP access records and even if they did, what could a small web company do but pass this on to relevant law enforcement?

Comment: @JimLewis I Agree, give me a moment to refactor this.

Comment: I agree that I might not have worded this so well, but web advertising is most likely responsible for the bulk of http requests on the internet and both publisher & advertisers cannot afford to put a "human" touch to the presented problem so it seems natural that there must be a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

note - Was originally part of question, but moved this part to be a standalone answer.  Marked as community wiki.

A simple solution would be to put a proxy script/service between advertisers and the publisher that then used a dedicated memcache array.

```
def handle_request(request):
    cache = Cache()
    key = getKeyByInterval(request.remote_ip,  hour = 1 )
    #Key == "YYMMDD_hour_ip"
    cache.add(key, 1)
    if cache.get(request.remote_ip) > threshold:
        redirect("/none_revenue/random_image")
    else:
        serve_advert()
```

Set threshold to 10, and only 10 adverts would be served to a specific IP for 1 hour.... but even that has flaws inherent to most advertising platforms where the advert script widget is an href like "http://Acme-Advertising-co.com/adserve?userid={Some unique id}&zoneid=SomeValue" in which case all the attacker needs to do is copy that script tag and make a curl request with doctored referer headers.

Comment: I think this method is good, but if advertisers see a lot of clicks for 1 specific IP, they'll know something is up. So I don't see the need to prevent that user case. What I'd be worried about is a lot of clicks from different IPs that are sent from bots or proxies for the purpose of fraud